# Creating flexible date ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I want to make my query more flexible with dates. I am thinking of defining variables with reference to current date. currently I am coding the exact date for the last quarter, the quarter before and the quarter one year ago.

That is the query for Q1:

```
select '2020_Q1' as time_frame, id, status, date, agent, country, sale 
from sales 
where date >= '2020-01-01' and date < '2020-03-31'
```

I do the same for Q4 and Q1 (2019) and union in the end. Today is April 27, let's say it is 4 months from now and it is August 27th. Now, I would want to look at Q2,Q1 and Q2(2019). I believe, I would need to work with current_date, but let me know if you think there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()` to get the start of the "current quarter":

```
select ...
from sales
where date => date_trunc('quarter', current_date)
  and date < date_trunc('quarter', current_date) + interval '3 months'
```