# Selecting data based off rolling quarter value

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a condition that will filter for dates in the next 8 quarters worth of data, based on the current quarter. The issue is this needs to be rolling. For example, as I'm writing this, it is 2/2/2023. The data condition would need to be such that it takes the data in the current quarter (i.e., Q1), and subsequently the current quarter +1, + 2, etc. The issue is when I get to a new year, as PostgreSQL does not allow you to do `datefield + interval '1 quarter'`. So, when I need an automated way of pulling the data for Q1 in 2023, I can't simply use the interval.  This is also an issue when, say, I get to Q4. I can't do `datefield + interval '1 quarter'`, because that gives Q5, which does not exist.

Any tips for getting this taken care of? My current thinking is that i need to create conditional logic where, if current quarter is Q4, filter where data is in Q1 of current year + 1, but am wondering if there are more efficient ways of doing this.

My current (and incomplete) solution is as follows:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where extract(quarter from datefield) = extract(quarter from current_date + interval '1 quarter')
    and datefield >= concat(extract(year from current_date), '-01-01')::date
    and datefield <= current_date + interval '2 years'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After another hour or so of digging, I found another post which answered this question:

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458301/creating-flexible-date-ranges-in-postgresql?rq=1)

The solution relies on date_trunc, which makes lots of sense.